# how to centerlize a box in the very center of the paper?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I am trying to draw a box in the center of the current page (A4 size). I try the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees,shapes.misc}   

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[color=gray,line width=1pt]
      \draw (-15cm,0) -- (1cm,0) -- (1cm,16cm) -- (-15cm,16cm) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I am manually change the coordinates of the corners of the box, but it doesn't help. It doesn't really locate in the center of the page.

Comment: thanks. I want to make it centralized relative to the paper's edges. But the current issue is it will be centralized vertically only but not horizontally. I try \begin{center} end{center} too, doesn't help.

Comment: If you tikz picture contains only the rectangle, you don't need to draw like you did. Use `\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);` and just change the coordinates of the upper right corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `current page.center` node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \begin{scope}[color=gray,line width=1pt]
\foreach \shift in {1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm}
      \draw ([xshift=-\shift,yshift=\shift]current page.center) rectangle ([xshift=\shift,yshift=-\shift]current page.center);
    \end{scope}
\node at (current page.center) {a};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above code will produce squares centered at `current page.center`, which is the intersection point of the line going from the upper left corner of the paper to the lower right corner, with the line going from the lower left corner to the upper right corner; if you want them to be centered in the "center of the text area", then you can use the `tikzpagenodes` and its `current text area.center` node instead; the two nodes might be different as the following example demonstrates; the red circle is centered at `current page.center` and the green circle is centered at `current page text area.center` (in a `a4paper` size the difference is not so big, but still noticeable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
\draw[red] (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west);
\node[draw,circle,red] at (current page.center) {};

\begin{scope}[color=gray,line width=1pt]
\foreach \shift in {1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm,6cm}
  \draw 
  ([xshift=-\shift,yshift=\shift]current page.center) 
  rectangle   
  ([xshift=\shift,yshift=-\shift]current page.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[green] (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.south east);
\draw[green] (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.south west);
\node[draw,circle,red] at (current page.center) {};
\node[draw,circle,green] at (current page text area.center) {};

\begin{scope}[color=gray,line width=1pt]
\foreach \shift in {1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm,6cm}
  \draw 
  ([xshift=-\shift,yshift=\shift]current page text area.center) 
  rectangle   
  ([xshift=\shift,yshift=-\shift]current page text area.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new request was made in a comment to the answer: to draw a horizontal line through the center; since the width of the line was nor specified, I show two possibilities: the width equals the width of the box, and the width equals `\paperwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\pagestyle{empty}
\def\shift{4cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[draw,circle,green] at (current page text area.center) {};% just to visualize the center
\begin{scope}[color=gray,line width=1pt]
\draw 
  ([xshift=-\shift,yshift=\shift]current page text area.center) 
  rectangle   
  ([xshift=\shift,yshift=-\shift]current page text area.center);
\end{scope}
% A horizontal rule having the same width as the box
\draw[line width=8pt,orange] 
  ([xshift=-\shift]current page text area.center) -- 
  ([xshift=\shift]current page text area.center);
% A horizontal rule having the same width as the page
\draw[ultra thick,blue] 
  (current page.west|-current page text area.center) -- 
  (current page.east|-current page text area.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user1285419 You're welcome! I added some new information to my answer, which could be useful for you. Also, don't forget to accept the answer, if you consider it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I am not quite familiar with using the tikzpagenodes. I used your code to plot a centralized box and I would like to add a horizontal line through the center of the box and parallel to the base line. Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: @user1285419 Sure! Please see my updated answer.